# can we install an openvswitch on any virtual machine?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtual-machine, switch

I want to install `openvswitch` on a virtual machine, so that other softwares along the switch functionality can be used. My questions are:

1. Is it possible to install `openvswitch` on a VM with `ubuntu` along with other softwares?
2. Does [GNS-3](https://gns3.com/) provides such or similar functionality? any recommendation for simulation tools.

Please help me, I am new to these kind of stuff and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Gns-3 can do this...

Comment: Thanks Tim, any points would be helpful

Comment: You have some reading to do, how are you emulating the gns-3 v-machines?

Comment: I have installed GN-3 on a local PC with one VM, tried created few test topologies but am not sure those switches can store any other software?

Comment: https://docs.gns3.com/docs/emulators/which-emulators-should-i-use/